# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I decided to try and build a simple web browser with python, but even after running `pip install PyQt5` and `PyQtWebEngine` I still get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'`.

And before you redirect me to the many other posts on this topic I have tried most of the solutions not they do not work. (I do have the latest version of pip)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it nvm (I installed python 3.11)